# Copy rows from one sheet into other sheet and after 7 columns go to next row using vba in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets, one filled with data and other one empty. I want to reshape the data on the other sheet by putting it into the next row every 7 columns.

This is my code, but it's not working. Can you help me to find the mistake that I'm making?

```
Set ws1 = Sheets("F2")
Set ws2 = Sheets("List1")

rangerow = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
rangecol = ws1.Range("A" & Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
rangerow2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
rangecol2 = ws2.Range("A" & Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To 100
  If j < 8 Then
    ws1.Range("A4").Copy
    ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ws2.Activate
    j = j + 1
  Else
    Row = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
  End If
  i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: we can guess, but it would be helpful if you'll show us what you mean. How is the data structured on the original sheet, and what is the desired result on the second  sheet ?

Comment: Also, if you have `For i = 1 To 100` you don't need to use `i = i + 1`, that's why you are using a `For` loop for `i`

Comment: And you copy always the same range `Range("A4")` to the same destination `Range("A1")`. Try to use `Cells(row, column)` to access a specific row and column

Comment: @ShaiRado The original data is in 27 rows and 31 column. And I want to paste it on the other sheet reshaped so it doesn't go past the 7th column, so every time "i" gets to 7, the row splits and continues in the next row.

Comment: Two issues: (1) You should initialize `j` to start from 1, and re-set it to 1 every time you finish the 7-values row (this last would go in the `else` section). (2) DO NOT increase `I`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `Set` your range in `"F2"` sheet to be dynamic, and then loop through each cell in the Range by using `For Each C In Rng`.

Inside this loop, I have `CellCount` which represent the number of the cell inside the Range, every 7 columns I reset the column number here:

```
Col = CellCount Mod 7 ' get the column number , every 7 columns reset the column
```

and add 1 to the Row here:

```
PasteRow = Int((CellCount - 1) / 7) + 1 ' get the row number
```

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyUpto7Columns()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range, C As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, CellCount As Long
Dim PasteRow As Long, Col As Long

Set ws1 = Sheets("F2")
Set ws2 = Sheets("List1")

With ws1
    ' get dynamic last row
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' set the range object in sheet "F2" up to column 31
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 31))
End With

PasteRow = 1 ' start pasting from the first row
CellCount = 1 ' reset cell count in Range

' loop through range (cell by cell)
For Each C In Rng
    PasteRow = Int((CellCount - 1) / 7) + 1 ' get the row number

    Col = CellCount Mod 7 ' get the column number , every 7 columns reset the column
    If Col = 0 Then Col = 7

    ws2.Cells(PasteRow, Col).Value = C.Value
    CellCount = CellCount + 1
Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: Works and does what I need. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, i As Long, j As Long
i = 1
j = 1

Set ws1 = Sheets("F2")
Set ws2 = Sheets("List1")

With ws1
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

For Each cell In ws1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    ws2.Cells(i, j) = cell
    j = j + 1
    If j = 8 Then
        i = i + 1
        j = 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlLeft).Column` says "Application-defined of object -defined error".

Comment: @EnnaSmile Try now

Answer (score 1):

Try The code below :) :

```
Sub test()

Set ws1 = Sheets("F2")
Set ws2 = Sheets("List1")

rangerow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
rangecol = ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


ii = 1
jj = 1
For i = 1 To rangerow
  For j = 1 To rangecol

      If jj = 8 Then
        ii = ii + 1
        jj = 1
      End If

      ws1.Cells(i, j).Copy
      ws2.Cells(ii, jj).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      jj = jj + 1
   Next j
Next i


 End Sub
```